# Does Ubuntu not provide debuginfod for gdb?

Tags: gdb

The operating system I am currently using is Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish).

I referred to Ubuntu's Service - Debuginfod official documentation,
link: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-debuginfod

And add `export DEBUGINFOD_URLS="https://debuginfod.ubuntu.com"` to .bashrc as described in the documentation.

Now I can use gdb gcc to get the relevant debuginfo prompt information, as shown below:

```
Reading symbols from gcc...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/6d/b0b50ebf17b931988c0e36786507e5c58fe192.debug...
```

But when I use gdb gdb, I get **No debugging symbols found in gdb**.
Does Ubuntu not yet provide debuginfo for gdb?

Thanks for any reply.

Comment: Yes, I want to debug the debugger.

Comment: If you inspect the package list [located here](http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/dists/jammy/main/binary-amd64/Packages), there is a package for `gdb-dbgsym`. So it should be available.

Comment: So is there some reason why gdb-dbgsym cannot correctly link to the Ubuntu Debuginfo server? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: That I don't know..

Comment: After adding the `export` statement to `.bashrc`, did you start a new shell? Or did you run the `export` statement in your current shell as well?

Comment: Hi muru: I have used source .bashrc, and start a new bash

Comment: Hmm, looking at https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gdb, the original version packaged for `gdb` in `jammy` is `12.0.90-0ubuntu1`, and it has since been superseded by `12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04` in `jammy-updates`. But the list given by @ArturMeinild specifies version `12.0.90-0ubuntu1`. And if I downgrade using `apt install gdb=12.0.90-0ubuntu1`, `gdb` then shows: "Downloading 36.60 MB separate debug info for /usr/bin/gdb". Looks like the newer package doesn't have debug symbols published yet.

Comment: I also successfully downloaded debuginfod after adjusting it to gdb-12.0.90-0ubuntu1. Thank muru's help.